# What does Tensor do to the values next to the vector?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, quantum-computation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3geEd.jpg)

Like you can see in the picture, there is a 1/SQR(2)

What exactly happens to this value when you use tensor. I assumed that you would just multiply the fractions leaving you with 1/2, but my friend got a different answer

would appreciate some help! thanks

Comment: You should try to write the expression on your answer, and not post external links for images.

Comment: Okay I'll do it now

Comment: The image is totally unclear, it misses everything. If you are not clear on what you ask we cannot give you any answer

Comment: it was a dumb question anyway, i solved it